# How can I get this in the title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get this link to go in the same block as the title. When I look at the page.php or index.php, I do not see the_title anywhere. All I see is the following:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>   
</div>
```

If you view the page now you will see my share button above the content (Share icon with text "Share this event").

```
<div class="share-button"><div>
```

But I am trying to get it next to the title. Can someone tell me which php file contains this code so I can add it?

The page is http://isaevent.com/event/new-year-kick-off/

Comment: Do a find in all files in your favourite text editor / php IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is using an events calendar plugin. You can create custom templates to make your changes. Here's how: http://tri.be/support/documentation/events-calendar-themers-guide/

It also tells you how to change the plugin files, but I wouldn't recommend that because you'll lose your changes if you update the plugin.

Comment: Joe, thanks so much! I was able to copy over the single-event.php file into my childe theme and add the code their. Works perfectly.